# Запятая при деепр.обороте

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией в предложении: «Она влилась в группу смутно знакомых лиц и определив среди девушек самую красивую, направилась к ней».

Я не могу понять, нужна ли запятая после союза «и», если переставить деепр.оборот, то получится: она влилась в группу смутно знакомых лиц и направилась к ней, а в этом нет смысла...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна:
*Она влилась в группу смутно знакомых лиц и, определив среди девушек самую красивую, направилась к ней.*

Деепричастный оборот после союза "и" отделяется с двух сторон независимо от корректности предложения после его изъятия. В данном случае при изъятии оборота предложение остаётся структурно корректным, проблема лишь в том, что "к ней" ссылается на элемент деепричастного оборота. Но это не даёт повода не ставить запятую. В случаях с другими оборотами (помимо деепричастного) при таких "перекрёстных ссылках" наблюдается то же (они не влияют на пунктуацию).

Исключение составляют те случаи, когда деепричастный оборот (или одиночное деепричастие) стоит после противительного союза "а". || В таких случаях при изъятии нарушается не только смысл, но и структура.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна и перед союзом «и» и после него. В данном случае союз и соединяет однородные сказуемые: влилась и направилась. Правило такого.

Два деепричастных оборота, соединенные неповторяющимся союзом и, запятой не разделяются (как и другие однородные члены предложения в подобных случаях): Раз, идя по шумному, весёлому проспекту и чувствуя себя вместе с толпою жизнерадостным, он испытывал счастливое удовольствие (Фед.).

Но если союз и соединяет не деепричастные обороты, а другие конструкции (два сказуемых, две части сложносочиненного предложения), то запятая может стоять как перед союзом, так и после него (в соответствии с нужным правилом): Макар сидел на дровнях, слегка покачиваясь, и продолжал свою песню (Кор.); Я слез в канаву и, согнав впившегося в середину цветка и сладко и вяло заснувшего мохнатого шмеля, принялся срывать цветок (Л. Т.).

Ср. предложения с деепричастной конструкцией, в которых запятая стоит и перед союзом, и после него: Левинсон постоял немного, вслушиваясь в темноту, и, улыбнувшись про себя, зашагал ещё быстрее (Ф.)

См.  справочник Розенталя. § 20 ч. 1 п. 2